# Python board game grid

Tags: python, grid

I need to make a simple board game for school in python it has to have a grid sort of like a chess board individual spaces where the character can stand. But I have no idea how, we are not allowed to download anything since it's school computers. Also I need to make the character move. I just need this is the most simple form. The example the book gave us looked like this:

```
..........             
..P.......  
..........  
..T.......  
....T.....  
..........  
..T.......  
..........  
.........X
```

`P` is the player, `T` is a trap and `X` is the treasure. I don't need it exactly like that I just need a board like that and how to make the player move on it.

Answer (score 2):

As this question is not very precise the answer can't be as well; but maybe there are some general hints: 
-think about how to store the positions of the elements on the boards (lists (-> lines of the game) might be a good start) 
-think about what it means to move the figure (taking the list approach this means you can increment or decrement the position in the list or switch to another one) 
-think about how you could see that the player has fallen in to a trap/won (check if a position is already acquired before moving the figure)

Comment: Yeah I have done that I couldn't figure it out so I asked here.